# About slowloris dos attack in skype

Tags: exploit, vulnerability, known-vulnerabilities, ports, skype

So I scanned my home pc for fun with nmap "vuln" script and it said something about the slowloris vulerability at port 443 . So I started up slowloris.pl and it really worked . After that I wondered what was on port 443 and found through an nmap scan that it was skype . So here is my question/s : 
1) Is skype really having some kind of unpached vulnerablity / bad implementation in windows ?
2)What would be the worst case scenario of an successful slowloris attack on windows (besides temporary downtime of either the port or the whole networking in the affected computer )
3)How easyly exploitable is the vulerability ?
4) Is there any knowen solution ? Well I cant close the port because well 443 is 443 and I don´t wanna redirect all my encrypted traffic .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer part of your question. :)

2) The worst case scenario of Slorloris is a short-term denial of service (unless it's used as part of a social engineering attack against admins, perhaps).

3) Since you were able to replicate it, you already know the answer: it's easy! But there's one mitigation: if there's anything that blocks ports (firewall, router with NAT, etc), it's not exploitable at all.

I don't know the answer to 1) and 4), and googling "skype slowloris" doesn't surface any results. Are you 100% sure it was vulnerable? It's possible it's just a classic DoS (like port exhaustion), not slowloris.